# What degrees are possible for minimal polynomials?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

My friend is working on a question of the form:

> Suppose $E/F$ is a Galois extension with Galois group isomorphic to $G$ (a finite group). Find the set of possible degrees of elements of $E$ over $F$. (The field $F$ and the group $G$ are given, but $E$ are unknown. The extension has characteristic $0$.)

He's not really sure how to approach it, and neither am I. If I understand correctly, a degree of an element $e \in E$ over $F$ is the same as the degree of the minimal polynomial of $e$ over $F$. If so, we're trying to put some contraints on the possible minimal polynomials of a Galois extension based on the structure of the Galois group of that extension. I'm not really sure how to do this however, and we'd appreciate some help.

> **Question.** How does one approach questions like this in general?

Comment: Is the extension finite?

Comment: @Servaes, yes, $G$ is a finite group. I've just added that.

Comment: The degree of the extension is the order of the group. Then use the Tower Law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was very far off. Here's another answer, which is a more detailed version of Marc Paul's comment to my previous answer.

By the fundamental theorem of Galois theory there is a bijective correspondence between the set of intermediate fields of the extension $E/F$ and the set of subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. It is given explicitly by mapping an intermediate field $F\subset L\subset E$ to the subset of elements of $E$ that fix every element of $L$, i.e. to $\operatorname{Aut}(E/L)$, and conversely by mapping a subgroup $H\subset\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ to the set of elements of $E$ that are fixed by all elements of $H$, denoted $E^H$.

It is then a routine exercise to verify that for any subgroup $H\subset\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$ the intermediate field $F\subset E^H\subset E$ satisfies $[E:E^H]=|H|$. By the tower law it follows that
$$[E^H:F]=\frac{[E:F]}{E:E^H}=\frac{|\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)|}{|H|},$$
where the latter is the index of $H$ in $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. Hence the degrees of the intermediate fields of $E/F$ are precisely the indices of the subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. By the primitive element theorem, every intermediate field of $E/F$ is of the form $F(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in E$, and the set of degrees over $F$ of elements of $E$ is also precisely the set of indices of subgroups of $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$.